# moving median as a window function (UDAF) in Apache Spark SQL

Tags: time-series, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to implement the "moving median" function as a window function to use it in Apache Spark SQL.

I'm trying to implement it as a UDAF in Scala. The version of Spark is 1.6.1.

I tried 2 ways of calling my UDAF ("median"):

1) As an SQL query:

```
val timeSeries = ... // get a DataFrame
...
timeSeries.registerTempTable("time_series")
timeSeries.sqlContext.udf.register("median", new MedianUDAF)
val timeSeriesWithMovingAverage = timeSeries.sqlContext.sql(s"select *, median(value_column) over (partition by metrics_name order by time_column) from time_series")
```

The result was:

Failure(org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Couldn't find window function median;)

2) As a DataFrame API call:

```
val timeSeriesWithMovingAverage = timeSeries.withColumn("movingAvg", medianFunction(timeSeries("value_column")).over(windowSpec))
```

The result was:

Failure(java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: MedianUDAF(value#16) is not supported in a window operation.)

Is there any way to use UDAFs as window functions?
For example, to calculate moving median (not moving average but median).

Comment: In Spark 2.1+, to find (moving) median we can use functions `percentile` and `percentile_approx`. The following answer uses `expr` in PySpark to calculate moving median as a window function - you should be able to work your way into Scala:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061553/how-to-calculate-moving-median-in-dataframe#71545401

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe you cannot use `UDFs` or `UDAFs` within windowing functions. The windowing functions are not native to `Spark` -- they use Hive, which precludes using Spark-defined `UDFs` and `UDAFs`.

In theory, I suppose you could create your `UDAF` directly in Hive, and then call it from Spark. But that's not something I have tried before -- it just seems like it must be possible.